# i am using two buttons simultaneously in one component, i want only one button to work when i click it not the other button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently new at ReactJs. So, i have implemented two buttons in one container and i dont know how to make each one of them work separately. If i am clicking the first button then even the second button is executing. Can anyone suggest what changes can I make in my code to make each button work separately. So, now i have updated the code, As

```
import { Select, Form, Input, Button, DatePicker, Icon } from 'antd';
import './CreatePrescription.scss';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const { Option } = Select;
const { TextArea } = Input;

class CreatePrescriptionFormData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    formType: 'add-patient',
    prescriptionItems: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }

      // Should format date value before submit.
      const fieldsValues = {
        ...values,
        'date-picker': values['date-picker'].format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      };
      console.log('Received values of form: ', fieldsValues);
    });
  };

  addprescriptionItem() {
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: [...this.state.prescriptionItems, ''] });
    console.log({ prescriptionItems: [...this.state.prescriptionItems, ''] });
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    this.state.prescriptionItems[index] = e.target.value;

    // set the changed state
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: this.state.prescriptionItems });
  }

  handleRemove(index) {
    // remove ana item at the index
    this.state.prescriptionItems.splice(index, 1);

    console.log(this.state.prescriptionItems, '$$$$');

    // update the state
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: this.state.prescriptionItems });
  }
  addprescriptionItems() {
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: [...this.state.prescriptionItems, ''] });
    console.log({ prescriptionItems: [...this.state.prescriptionItems, ''] });
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    this.state.prescriptionItems[index] = e.target.value;

    // set the changed state
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: this.state.prescriptionItems });
  }

  handleRemove(index) {
    // remove ana item at the index
    this.state.prescriptionItems.splice(index, 1);

    console.log(this.state.prescriptionItems, '$$$$');

    // update the state
    this.setState({ prescriptionItems: this.state.prescriptionItems });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const tailFormItemLayout = {
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: {
          span: 24,
          offset: 0,
        },
        sm: {
          span: 16,
          offset: 4,
        },
      },
    };
    return (
      <div className="comp-wrap">
        <Helmet
          titleTemplate="%s - Sample-App"
          defaultTitle="Create Prescription | Sample-App"
        >
          <meta name="description" content="sample application" />
        </Helmet>

        <div className="component-title">
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Add Prescription</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="cards-wrap row justify-content-md-center">
            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div className="prescription-form">
                <div className="login-form" style={{ borderRadius: '5px' }}>
                  <div className="pr-login-box">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <div>
                        <Form.Item label="Start" className="prescription_date">
                          {getFieldDecorator('start', {
                            rules: [
                              {
                                type: 'object',
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please select date!',
                              },
                            ],
                          })(<DatePicker />)}
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item label="End" className="prescription_date">
                          {getFieldDecorator('end', {
                            rules: [
                              {
                                type: 'object',
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please select date!',
                              },
                            ],
                          })(<DatePicker />)}
                        </Form.Item>
                      </div>
                      {this.state.prescriptionItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="new-item" key={index}>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="What"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('what', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select Medicine!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="">Abhayarishtam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Amritarishtam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Ashtachurnam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">Brahmi Ghritam</Option>
                                  <Option value="">
                                    Amritotharam Kashayam
                                  </Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item
                              label="When"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('when', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select When">
                                  <Option value="morning">Morning</Option>
                                  <Option value="afternoon">Afternoon</Option>
                                  <Option value="evening">Evevning</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="Quantity"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                              style={{ width: '15%' }}
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('quantity', {
                                rules: [
                                  // {
                                  //     required: true,
                                  //     message: 'Please select!',
                                  // },
                                ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select Quantity">
                                  <Option value="1/2">1/2</Option>
                                  <Option value="1">1</Option>
                                  <Option value="2">2</Option>
                                  <Option value="3">3</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="Unit"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                              style={{ width: '15%' }}
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('unit', {
                                // rules: [
                                //     {
                                //         required: true,
                                //         message: 'Please select!',
                                //     },
                                // ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="ltr">ltr</Option>
                                  <Option value="grm">grm</Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                              label="How Often"
                              className="prescription_date field_width"
                            >
                              {getFieldDecorator('often', {
                                // rules: [
                                //     {
                                //         required: true,
                                //         message: 'Please select!',
                                //     },
                                // ],
                              })(
                                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                                  <Option value="after_meal">After Meal</Option>
                                  <Option value="before_meal">
                                    Before Meal
                                  </Option>
                                </Select>,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                              {getFieldDecorator('notes')(
                                <TextArea rows={3} />,
                              )}
                            </Form.Item>
                            {/* <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)} value={item}></input> */}
                            <a
                              className="remove"
                              onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}
                            >
                              <Icon type="close-circle" />
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}
                      <Button
                        onClick={e => this.addprescriptionItem(e)}
                        className="btn"
                        type="primary"
                      >
                        Add Prescription Item
                      </Button>

                      <Button
                        onClick={e => this.addprescriptionItems(e)}
                        className="btn"
                        type="primary"
                      >
                        Add Compound Medicine
                      </Button>

                      <Form.Item {...tailFormItemLayout} className="form-btn">
                        <Button
                          className="cl-clone"
                          type="button"
                          htmlType="button"
                        >
                          Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          className="cl-fill btn-h-40 btn-save float-right"
                          type="primary"
                          htmlType="submit"
                        >
                          Save
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CreatePrescription = Form.create({ name: 'coordinated' })(
  CreatePrescriptionFormData,
);

export default CreatePrescription;
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So, these are two different buttons with different functionality. So, when i click the first button, it gives me five columns of what, when,quantity,unit and how often in a dropdown menu and i can add those values for each medicine which i choose. Now with the second button i want to keep the functionalities such as when, what static, i dont want them to change for each medicine. they should stay the same. So, one button should not keep the functions static and other function should keep those functions static

Answer (score 0):

```
addprescriptionItem and addprescriptionItems
```

are doing exactly the same stuff. 
Can u please elaborate more what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: So, these are two different buttons with different functionality. So, when i click the first button, it gives me five columns of what, when,quantity,unit and how often in a dropdown menu and i can add those values for each medicine which i choose. Now with the second button i want to keep the functionalities such as  when, what static, i dont want them to change for each medicine. they should stay the same. So, one button should not keep the functions static and other function should keep those functions static. So, when i am running the code if i am clicking the first button

Comment: automatically the second button dropdown also adds up. I just want one button to work at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to do some logic in the functions.   Currently, you are just doing this, which doesn't look like it does much useful:

```
this.setState({ prescription items: [...this.state.prescriptionItems, ''] });
```

One button is called ' Add Compound Medicine' so I'm guessing you want to add or remove things from the items array, e.g.o something with the data being passed back:

```
addprescriptionItems(e) {
    console.log(e);
    const item = // whatever
    this.state.prescriptionItems.push(item)
}
```

Comment: So, basically when i click the first button, it gives me five columns of what, when,quantity,unit and how often in a dropdown menu and i can add those values for each medicine whichever i choose. Now with the second button i want to keep the functionalities such as when, what static, i dont want them to change for each medicine. they should stay the same. So, one button should not keep the functions static and other function should keep those functions static. So, when i am running the code if i am clicking the first button

Comment: For the first button, i want the fields to be added to everytime i click the button and for the second button i want them to be static.